I use near view with a contract method and get a MethodNotFound error, but the contract was deployed successfully
I created a .wasm file using this Rust code
use near_sdk::borsh::{self, BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize};
use near_sdk::{near_bindgen, env};

const PASSWORD_NUMBER: u8 = 1;

#[near_bindgen]
#[derive(Default, BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize)]
pub struct Contract {
    // SETUP CONTRACT STATE
    password_solution: String,
}

#[near_bindgen]
impl Contract {
    #[init]
    pub fn new(solution: String) -> Self {
        Self {
            password_solution: solution,
        }
    }

    pub fn get_password_number(&self) -> u8{
        PASSWORD_NUMBER
    }

    pub fn set_solution(&mut self, solution: String) {
        self.password_solution = solution;
    }

    pub fn get_solution(&self) -> String {
        self.password_solution.clone()
    }

    pub fn guess_solution(&mut self, solution: String) -> bool {
        if solution == self.password_solution {
            env::log_str("Success");
            true
        } else {
            env::log_str("Fail");
            false
        }
    }
}

/*
 * the rest of this file sets up unit tests
 * to run these, the command will be:
 * cargo test --package rust-template -- --nocapture
 * Note: 'rust-template' comes from Cargo.toml's 'name' key
 */

// use the attribute below for unit tests
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use near_sdk::test_utils::{get_logs, VMContextBuilder};
    use near_sdk::{testing_env, AccountId};

    // part of writing unit tests is setting up a mock context
    // provide a `predecessor` here, it'll modify the default context
    fn get_context(predecessor: AccountId) -> VMContextBuilder {
        let mut builder = VMContextBuilder::new();
        builder.predecessor_account_id(predecessor);
        builder
    }

    // debugging and iteration of a unit test

    // TESTS HERE
    #[test]
    fn debug_get_hash() {

        testing_env!(VMContextBuilder::new().build());

        let debug_solution = "tamago clarian";
        let debug_hash_bytes = env::sha256(debug_solution.as_bytes());
        let debug_hash_string = hex::encode(debug_hash_bytes);
        println!("Let's debug: {:?}", debug_hash_string);
    }

    #[test]
    // write a function that will guess the solution
    // get an account ID
    // set up a testing context and test environment
    // set up the contract for the test - call a new method

    fn check_guess_solution() {
        let clarian = AccountId::new_unchecked("clarian.testnet".to_string());
        let context = get_context(clarian);
        testing_env!(context.build());

        let mut contract = Contract::new("e9242595b2be15297c7a9b0433e22c3d95a2c013b0635ec0a37a14b3f9e8146c".to_string(),);

        let mut guess_result = contract.guess_solution("wrong answer".to_string());
        assert!(!guess_result, "Expectation: This is incorrect");
        assert_eq!(get_logs(), ["You shall not pass. Please try again."], "Expected a failure in logs");
        // set the guess_result variable to the correct password and return
        // the assertion so that it checks guess result with the expected string which
        // should say that it passes
        guess_result = contract.guess_solution("tamago clarian".to_string());
        assert!(guess_result, "Expectation: This is the correct answer");
        assert_eq!(get_logs(), ["You shall not pass. Please try again.", "You may enter! This is the right password"], "Expected a successful log
        after previous failed");
    }
}


and deployed it to Near. When I call this API request https://docs.near.org/api/rpc/contracts#view-contract-code, as was suggested in this question Why near-cli can't find my contract method?, I receive a long code_base64 value, which, I guess, means that the contract was deployed successfully.

When I use near view password.vitalii320.testnet get_solution or near view password.vitalii320.testnet get_password_number, I receive a MethodNotFound error. 
Please, help me with this issue

When I use near view get_solution or near view get_password_number, I receive a MethodNotFound error. near view <contractName> <methodName> Post full command please, otherwise it looks like you missed the contractName

@khorolets, thanks, I edited the view commands exactly as I used them

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Could you please provide scripts that you run to build and deploy the project?
It's very likely that you've deployed another WASM file. Because NearBlocks Explorer says your contract implements only function main

According to NearBlocks Explorer, the only function your contract implements is main

Revise the file you've previously deployed to the account and redeploy with the proper one

Another way to get the list of implemented functions in the contract is through the near.cli.rs - it's a newer CLI that has many more features and provides intuitive experience
Just install it using the instructions in the Readme and run near command to trigger interactive mode or paste your predefined command
Here's the command you'd need to inspect the contract state:
near contract inspect password.vitalii320.testnet network-config testnet now


